# Why promise catch is still getting resolved value

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I m trying to understand why promise catch with null parameter still getting the resolved value 1

```js
var x = Promise.resolve(1);
var p1 = x.catch(null);
p1.then((x) => {
  console.log(x)
}); // logs 1
```

Comment: Promise catch doesn't return a new promise

Comment: `.then` takes two callbacks `(onFullfilled, onRejeced)` and `.catch` is (was?) simply "sugar" for `.then(null, onRejected)` ... I like to think of promises having two chains ... fulfilled and rejected ... and any `.then` that doesn't include a "handler" for one of these, simply "passes on" the "value" of that chain to the next `.then`

Comment: oh, by the way ... it's also like you're doing `Promise.resolve(1).then().then(x => console.log(x))` ... you could even do `Promise.resolve(1).then().then().then().then().then(x => console.log(x))`

Comment: What is the point of `var p1 = x.catch(null);`?  I can think of no useful reason for doing that.  Besides `.catch()` is supposed to be passed a function reference, not a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns 1 because you code never reaches catch block. To reach it you must reject your promise. even literally (`Promise.reject()`) or throwing an error:

Example 1: everything is ok cause no rejections:

```js
Promise
.resolve(1)
.then(x => {
  console.log(x);
  return x + 1;
})
.then(x => {
  console.log(x);
  return x + 1;
})
.then(x => {
  console.log(x);
  return x + 1;
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log('an error!!'); // block not reached
});
```

Example 2: a reject promise jump to next catch block:

```js
Promise
.resolve(1)
.then(x => {
  console.log(x);
  return x + 1;
})
.then(x => {
  console.log(x);
  throw Error('ops');
  return x + 1;
})
.then(x => { // block not reached
  console.log(x);
  return x + 1;
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log('an error!!');
});
```

Example 3: after catch block it runs normally:

```js
Promise
.resolve(1)
.then(x => {
  console.log(x);
  return x + 1;
})
.then(x => {
  console.log(x);
  throw Error('ops');
  return x + 1;
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log('an error!!');
  return 10;
})
.then(x => {
  console.log(x);
  return x + 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When x resolves , it has value 1 
When you try to catch x, it returns x with catch handler added on itself, therefore p1 refers to x itself but with additional catch handlers
Now as p1 which inherited from x is already resolved, chaining any then methods will run with resolved x arguments , hence this behavior